# Percent word question

Tags: percentages

My son is stuck on this maths homework question and I do not know how to do this. The question says: "there are $682$ girls in a crowd of $1000$. What percent is this". Use no calculator.

We have done $\dfrac{682}{1000}$ and simplified to $\dfrac{341}{500}$ but now am stuck...how do I get this into a percentage?

Comment: Hint. It shouldn't be too hard to divide the numerator and denominator by 5 without a calculator. (There will be a remainder in the numerator, so there will be a fraction of a percent in the answer.)

Answer (score 3):

We can also solve it by making proportional.

Let $682$ of $1000$ is $x$%

Now, make the proportion,

$$\dfrac{682}{1000}=\dfrac{x}{100}$$

$$1000x = 68200$$

$$x = \dfrac{68200}{1000}$$
          $$= 68.2%$$

Thus, $682$ of $1000$ is $68.2$%

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{682}{1000}=\frac{68.2}{100.0}=68.2\%$$

Answer (score 2):

you need multiply by 100, i.e.

$$\frac{682}{1000}\times100=68,2\%$$

Comment: Ah...yes...not done any maths in 30 years...makes sense now!

Comment: Well, technically, $68.2\%=\frac{682}{1000}$. Multiplication by $100$ is to get from the *decimal presentation* to the *percentage presentation*.

Answer (score 2):

There are $682$ girls per $1000$ people, hence $68$ per $100$ ! (Precisely $68.2$, but I don't want to harm anyone.)

Answer (score 0):

To convert a fraction into percent, simply multiply the fraction by 100, like-

$$\dfrac{1}{10}\;\;\implies\dfrac{1}{10}\times100=10\%$$

similarly,

$\dfrac{682}{1000}\;\;\implies\dfrac{682}{1000}\times100=68.2\%$